# Number of worker thread per message type

Tags: nservicebus

There is a settings in NService configuration to set how many number of threads process the message. I believe this is for per worker node.

For Instance, If I have worker node that is processing more than one message type. Is there a feature in NService bus, that enable us to set number of thread per message type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not that I'm aware of. The NServiceBus philosophy is that you should have one or a limited number of message types that are handled by a single endpoint. If you have message types that have different requirements in terms of processing priority, that may be a sign that you need distinct nodes.